# Deploy Grails 2.5 app to Tomcat8

Tags: tomcat, grails

I'm trying to deploy a Grails v2.5.0 app to Tomcat 8.0.22 and getting the following error:

```
2015-07-25 13:11:09,714 ERROR [GrailsContextLoaderListener] - Error initializing Grails: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
net/sf/cglib/proxy/UndeclaredThrowableException
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext
resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method
failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
net/sf/cglib/proxy/UndeclaredThrowableException     at
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
net/sf/cglib/proxy/UndeclaredThrowableException     at
java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)     ... 5 more Caused by:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
net.sf.cglib.proxy.UndeclaredThrowableException     ... 6 more
25-Jul-2015 13:11:09.715 SEVERE [wwww startStop-1]
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception
sending context initialized event to listener instance of class
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext
resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method
failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
net/sf/cglib/proxy/UndeclaredThrowableException     at
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
net/sf/cglib/proxy/UndeclaredThrowableException     at
java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)     ... 5 more Caused by:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
net.sf.cglib.proxy.UndeclaredThrowableException     ... 6 more
```

`net/sf/cglib` has been added afterwards to tomcat8 shared lib folder, but it's only causing `net/sf/cglib/proxy/UndeclaredThrowableException`
Never met that in the develomement mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be only two reasons for this. The first one is that, either your WAR is containing two versions of jars for a required library `cglib` and the second is that your WAR does not contain this library at all.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cglib/cglib/3.1

Due to any of the above, you will always get `NoClassDefFoundError`. But, you can easily fix this. When you deploy your WAR file to Tomcat, the WAR file is extracted, then `ls` into the exploded WAR's `lib` folder: `ls -al $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/` and look for a jar file named `cglib-*.jar`.

Now, there can be two possibilities as I described above, either there will be no jar file with name `cglib` available or there will be two jars of name `cglib` with two different version.

The solution for the first case, you can add a dependency into your `BuildConfig.groovy`  like: `compile 'cglib:cglib:2.2.2'`.

And for the second case, you can use `grails dependency-report` to see how that library is being duplicated and can **exclude** from one.

Note: For second step, if you want an immediate fix, you can just delete one of the `jar` from the location I specified and restart the Tomcat.

Comment: Adding cglib to Tomcat libraries should have made the trick, BUT it was irrelevant to add it without its own dependencies (i.e cglib-nodep.jar).

Comment: Thanks. It 's still cleaner to get it in buildConfig.groovy.